# Warning: Missing argument 2 for customvishal_form() in Drupal 7 :

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have made a custom module and it works fine till I start working on my custom theme.

Once I move over to my custom theme I get this error

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for customvishal_form(), called in
>   /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/new/includes/theme.inc on line 1029 and
>   defined in customvishal_form() (line 441 of
>   /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/new/sites/all/modules/customvishal/customvishal.module).

You can see the error at : http://www.iamvishal.com/dev/about-us

I don't think anything is wrong with my code  :

```
/**
* A simple form.
*/
function customvishal_form($form, &$form_submit) {
$form['customvishalactivate'] = array(
'#title' => t('Activate Preference'),
'#type' => 'radios',
'#options' => array('1' => t('Yes'), '0' => t('No')),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
return $form; 
}
```

Its called from

```
function customvishal_pref($arg1)
{
 // Here we willl make the form and save the data so when cron
 // runs we will check the users preference
 $build = array(
'header_text' => array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<p>' . t('This page is where you add your preferences. Based on your      
  entered choices we will send you alerts ') . '</p>',
 ),
 'example_form' => drupal_get_form('customvishal_form'),
 );
 return $build;

 }
```

What might be causing this problem ?

Cheers,
Vishal

Comment: I tried  many themes and can't replicate this problem. So it seems to be a theme  issue but I can't  seem to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the form function is called the only parameter that is sent to it is the form variable. Since your second function parameter doesn't have a default value it obviously produces a warning.

If you never use it in the function code you might consider removing it or providing a default value.

e.g.:

```
function customvishal_form($form, &$form_submit = NULL)
```

or you might consider passing an additional parameter. You can do this like so:

```
drupal_get_form('customvishal_form', $some_your_parameter);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue

I called hook_form like this:

> ```
> /**
>  * Implements of hook_menu().
>  */
> function skupina_menu() {
>   $items = array();
>   $items['admin/config/people/skupina'] = array(
>     'title' => 'Skupiny odborníkov',
>     'description' => 'Prehľady návštev odborníkov',
>     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
>     'page arguments' => array('skupina_statistics'),
>     'access arguments' => array('view statistics'),
>     'file' => 'admin.inc',
>     'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'skupina'), 
>     'weight' => 1,
>   );      
>   return $items;
> }
> ```

and then

> ```
> /**
>  * Prehlad navstev odbornikov - page
>  */
> function skupina_statistics($form, &$form_state) {
>
>   $form = array();
>   $form['skupina_obdobie'] = array(
>       '#type' => 'select', 
>       '#title' => t('Zmeniť zobrazenie'), 
>       '#options' => skupina_get_zobrazenia(),
>       '#description' => t('Zmení filtrovanie dát podľa zvolenej možnosti.'),
>       '#required' => FALSE, 
>   );  
>   return $form;
>
> }
> ```

my problem was, that the function didn't have the "_form" in its name so its produce those warnings.

So the function must be called `"skupina_statistics_form` in my case

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the answer. I had the exact same problem.

Is your module named exactly as your custom theme? Mine was and I changed my theme name and the error went away